# BUG WGET: set exit code to 1 if invalid host name specified

Tags: linux, unix, wget

We're using wget to do some connectivity tests, and relying mainly on
exit status to determine success/failure

```
wget https://
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
echo "Failed to retrieve data"
else
...
```

exits with a status of 0 (indicating success), even though wget
clearly prints "Invalid host name".. Can you please let me know how to catch this error ?

Thanks

Comment: `wget http://; echo $?` gives me a `1`

Comment: Hello @hek2mgl Thanks for your reply.
Try for the below host link:

    `https:///finance/buhrchy?data.schemaVersion=1&data.responseStatus=true&format=txt&data.delimiter=|&buhrchy.effToDt=2015-04-01&buhrchy.effToDt.relation=%3E%3D&buhrchy.effFromDt=2015-04-01&buhrchy.effFromDt.relation=%3C%3D`


I am getting Invalid host name with 0 exit status

Comment: @Explorer wget 1.18 here. `wget https:///finance/buhrchy?data.schemaVersion=1&data.responseS‌​tatus=true&format=tx‌​t&data.delimiter=|&b‌​uhrchy.effToDt=2015-‌​04-01&buhrchy.effToD‌​t.relation=%3E%3D&bu‌​hrchy.effFromDt=2015‌​-04-01&buhrchy.effFr‌​omDt.relation=%3C%3D; echo $?` prints 1.